MC Connector - how does it understand the relationship type when synchronizing objects?
I have noticed something weird today, which made me a little confused about how the connector actually works.
2 BUs, 1 Service Cloud Org, multi-org connector installed. There are two different integration users for each BU, which allows me to have separate synchronised DEs for each BU.
There is a custom object called Activity__c, which is related to Contact. Now, in the contact designer, on BU one those two are related as 1 to 1; on BU two as one to many.
How is this possible?
I looked at other relationships and some that should be one to many are actually connected as one to one.
How does exactly the connector "decide" what kind of relationship there should be between two synchronised DEs? Especially considering that on Sales&Service Cloud you can't really link two objects as one to one out of the box.
Is it actually safe to use contact data from the connector attribute group in journeys?

curious; generally: using one-to-many in Journeys is usually a bad idea in ANY scenario. Scenario: One Contact, many orders. Journey Builder: split people with order stage "sent". What a journey builder decision split will ask is always: Is there "AT LEAST ONE" order to this contact with stage "sent"? Even though "the right order" might be a different stage, the split will evaluate to true if at least one does.

The answer that nobody wants to hear is: preprocessing (with SQL, if in SFMC) or before you create an object to listen to with an event entry. in other words: NOT journey builder.

